# how to search a php object for text

Tags: php

I have a PHP object called `$result` which I can see the value of by using:

```
print_r($result);
```

I would like to search `$result` for specific text across the entire object just like if I viewed the result of `print_r($result)` and did a "find" through the web browser.

Unfortunately I am having difficulty doing this - I know that `isset` can search for properties but I am looking for more than properties since I am looking to search the text. I tried to run the following:

```
if (strpos($result,'[test] => lots of text to search') !== false) {
echo 'true';
}
```

But unfortunately nothing comes back (no error and no response). Any suggestions on how to search this object would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want to do

```
if (isset($result->test) && $result->test == "lots of text to search") {
    echo 'true';
}
```

but if you want to really search text result try

```
if (strpos(print_r($result, true),'[test] => lots of text to search') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: I think the asker should definitely learn how to use objects properly and not search a serialised/dumped object for values. Emphasizing that the first code snippet is definitely the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If your object is an array, you can try to use array_search()

The following is an example:

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>
```